# syntax of accessing json data loaded with $.getJSON

Tags: json, syntax, getjson

I have some really simple code on a button to load some json, and it's the data within the json I want to access:-

```
function loadJson(){
    var json = $.getJSON("samplejson.js");
    document.getElementById('header2').innerHTML = json;
}
```

The content of samplejson.js is:-

person = {
    "name"  : "Nicolas",
    "age"   : "22",
    "alive"     : true,
    "gender"    : "Male",
    "power"     : "1"
}

Clicking the button that runs the function returns [object Object] to the innerHTML.
I know that in this context, json is an object, so that's expected.

What I need syntax for is if I wanted to change innerHTML to "Nicholas" for example.
json.person.name does not work. Neither does json[0].name nor json.person[0].name . I've tried a few other variants and no success with any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getJSON` returns a jQuery asynchronous request object and not the result of the ajax call.  If you want data acquired from ajax, you need to use it in the callback.

```
$.getJSON("samplejson.js").done(function (json) {
    $("#header2").html(json);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't work for me though. I added in a few alerts so I could see how far it gets.. function loadJson(){
  alert("hello json");
  $.getJSON("samplejson.js").done(function (json) {
   $("#header2").html(json);
   alert(json);
  });
 } the first alert runs, the second does not.http://www.ggfxserve.co.uk/html5/adp/index.html

Comment: @galaxyg seems like `samplejson.js` does not emit JSON or is otherwise not working properly

Comment: Thanks! I've used some alternative JSON now and it all works.